# ATExtensions Record(s)Field - validators and validator tests

Tags: plone

I thought I'd start my test-writing career with validator tests.  The
first validator I decided to test was an ATExtensions RecordField defined like this:

```
class CoordinateField(RecordField):
    """ Stores angle in deg, min, sec, bearing """
    security = ClassSecurityInfo()
    _properties = RecordField._properties.copy()
    _properties.update({
        'subfield_validators' : {'degrees':'coordinatevalidator',
                                 'minutes':'coordinatevalidator',
                                 'seconds':'coordinatevalidator',
                                 'bearing':'coordinatevalidator'},
    'type' : 'angle',
    'subfields' : ('degrees', 'minutes', 'seconds', 'bearing'),
```

(incidentally, a side-question about the reason for using subfield_validators instead of a single field validator.  The only kind of Record(s)Field validation that actually fires, is a subfield_validator.  If anyone has an example of how to write a single validator for the RecordField itself, please will you share the secret? Not a real problem, but not pretty either)

Then, the actual test...

I know how to test the validator for an AT StringField:

```
self.assertEqual(instance.schema.get('Keyword').validate(
       'XX X', instance), 
       "Validation failed: 'XX X': is an invalid keyword."
)
```

The same should have been sufficient to test the RecordField:

```
self.assertEqual(instance.schema.get('Latitude').validate(
    {'degrees':'x', 'minutes':'x', 'seconds':'x', 'bearing':'x'}, instance), 
    "Validation failed: invalid co-ordinates."
)
```

But I get an AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'form'

Obviously the validator expects a request.  So I floundered around in the debugger for a while, following every validate/validate_validators function signature I could find (I don't think it would be productive at all to show my work), with one of two results.

a) A syntax error, or 
b) Validator failing to report failed validation (simply returning None).

Has anyone got an example of a test case for an ATExtensions Record(s)Field that I can crib?  There aren't any tests in Products.ATExtensions, and I'm lost.